# how to use compare field values in mongo compass

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "Employee": {
        "EmployeeData": {
        
                "basePay": "1000",
                "sumPayAmount": "2000"
            }


    }
},
{
    "Employee": {
        "EmployeeData": {
        
                "basePay": "4000",
                "sumPayAmount": "1000"
            }


    }
}
```

how to find the documents where `basePay` is greather than `sumPayAmount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `$expr` to compare both fields. And make sure to convert the value to decimal/integer before compare.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $toDecimal: "$Employee.EmployeeData.basePay"
      },
      {
        $toDecimal: "$Employee.EmployeeData.sumPayAmount"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RaS2gfjZIsO)